# Python : Pandas populating 3-D dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, 3d

I am not sure what options I have available to populate a 3-D data frame with information.  I have a list of stock tickers and embedded within in each ticker there are subcategories for Income Statement, Balance Sheet, and Cash Flows.  I have thought maybe it would be best to define a 3-D dictionary and use that to populate a data frame, or maybe directly populate an already structured data frame.  I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

3-D Dataframe is not a thing. You are looking for [Panels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).

I would build a DataFrame for each stock ticker, then create a dictionary of DataFrames, then feed that to Panel.

Comment: What I meant is a multi index data frame which would be the equivalent of a 3-d dataframe.  You still think a a dictionary of data frames to a panel is the best way?

Comment: I think I would. I haven't had that problem. You can then recover the multi-level index using: [to_dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#conversion-to-dataframe).